# Show that a limit does not exist

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I need show that $\lim_{x\longrightarrow 1}\dfrac{1}{x-1}$ does no exist.
My intent is the following, prove that $\lim_{x\longrightarrow 1^+}\dfrac{1}{x-1}=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\longrightarrow 1^-}\dfrac{1}{x-1}=-\infty$.

Let $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, then if $\delta=1/\alpha$ for every $x\in (1,\infty)$ where $0 < x-1< \delta$, then $\dfrac{1}{x-1}>\dfrac{1}{\delta}=\alpha$, so that $\dfrac{1}{x-1}>\alpha$, hence $\lim_{x\longrightarrow 1^+}\dfrac{1}{x-1}=\infty$

Let $\beta\in \mathbb{R}$, then if $\delta=1/\beta$ for every $x\in [0,1)$ where $0 < 1-x< \delta$, then $\dfrac{1}{1-x}>\dfrac{1}{\delta}=\beta$, so that $\dfrac{1}{x-1}<-\beta$, hence $\lim_{x\longrightarrow 1^-}\dfrac{1}{x-1}=-\infty$.

I have an error or you think it's okay.

Comment: It looks okay to me.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to give an explicit example, such as $x_n = 1+{1 \over n}$. Then ${1 \over 1-x_n} = n$ from which it is clear that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

It's all good, but note that for this particular purpose you don't need to compute limits, all you need is to observe that $$\cases{\frac{1}{x-1}<-1&for $x\in (0,1), $\\\frac{1}{x-1}>1&for $x\in (1,2). $}$$